# pdf reader which has zoom and width locking?

Tags: settings, pdf, ebook-reader, zooming

I have both Adobe Reader and EZPDF. Are are both lacking. I want to lock the width and zoom and everything once I have a pdf open to my preferred settings. I just want to page up or down when sliding/swiping.

In ezpdf the settings menu keeps popping up irregularly when I slide. Sometimes it zoomed in or out. I see the words 'ln' or 'sf' overlaying the pdf and I don't know what they mean. Some I am locked in a page. I can't on the next or previous page.

In adobe Reader I can't zoom in to will the width of the page. It has minimal settings.

Is there a pdf reader that displays the text to the full width of the screen and locks everything so it doesn't do erratic stuff?

Answer (score 4):

ezPDF has an option to remove this overlay: Bring up the popupmenu, tick Settings. In the Link section there is a checkbox marked "Indicate Link". Uncheck and the Ln overlay is gone.

Version 1.9.5.3

Answer (score 3):

I really find [APV PDF Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cx.hell.android.pdfview) much better than all the famous readers.

- On top of that, it's Open Source ([Google code project page](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)).

Comment: And what is that? An answer that is little more than a link to another site is not helpful. What is it? Why do you think it's better?

Answer (score 3):

The dev version of the [APV PDF Viewer (apv-0.3.3dev01)](http://code.google.com/p/apv/downloads/list) can do exactly what you want.

Comment: Release version (October 14, 2012) in play store works great, but make sure to go into the settings to choose what various taps and presses do. To get it work to my liking, I disabled the zoom buttons, and make the top/bottom taps go page up/down.

Answer (score 1):

In EZpdf, the "Ln" means there is a link on the page, and the "Sf" means you have horizontal scrolling locked (I have no idea what the f actually stands for).  Those overlays annoy me too, so I am going to decompile the apk and remove that text.  That should solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try [VuDroid](https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/). It's Free Software. (*I have issues with it on my PD Novel as it seems to not like resistive screens, but it's fine on my phone.*)

Another option is [DroidReader](https://code.google.com/p/droidreader/) which I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the individual files, not the app. If the file supports it, you can use the reflow text view in adobe reader which locks the width and allows you to zoom while still seeing the full width of the page. Some files don't support this.  Others only support it to a certain level of zoom. Apps that try to overide the docs settings can cause those inconsistencies you mentioned. I've found Beam Reader to be the most powerful pdf reader but my trial ran out and I wasn't willing to pay $10 for it.

Comment: I don't want to reflow the text. In iRead or iAnnotate on my iTouch I can zoom to a level I like and do a persistent lock on that level. I can't find app which does the same on the Android. It does this on any pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Mantano Reader does everything you want. It uses the same engine as Adobe Reader Mobile (Adobe Reader Mobile SDK), so it's very fast even on ARM v8 (initial Samsung Galaxy Tab).

It has some problems with color saturation though.

Answer (score -2):

ezPDf does exactly what you need....

Comment: OP complained about ezPDF. Can you explain to OP what needs to be done to make it work for their needs?

Answer (score -2):

ezPdf costs 1 dollar but is realy worth it

You can lock the scroll from the menu - the zoom setting is automatically saved
and you can go to the next page by pressing the small arrow on the lower right

Comment: OP complained about ezPDF, suggesting it as an answer is not helpful.